# Rendering a n-body simulation

Tags: c++, graphics, opencl, simulation, gpu

I'm using openCL to simulate a n-body problem. The output I'm getting is positions of particles in 3-dimensional space (x,y,z). What I want to do now is to render them frame by frame and was just wondering how I would go around to getting that done. I'm using C++ and do not have any previous experience with graphics.

If you could point me in the right direction that would be awesome.

Thanks

Comment: Change the C with a G. Tah dah!

Comment: You probably want to Google tutorials or check previous questions before posting something like this.

Comment: I was thinking about using ncurses and just doing a text display or something...but I want to do something better.

Answer (score 3):

If you're just looking for a graphics library to use, I recommend SFML. I am actually using it for a similar project right now and it works great! http://www.sfml-dev.org/

Comment: How steep is the learning curve for sfml?

Comment: It should be pretty straightforward: http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/graphics-shape.php

Comment: The learning curve for sfml is very shallow, I found it easy to use and had my graphics implementation up within an hour (which is less time than I spent looking for other libraries). They have an easy to follow tutorials section that will take you through the basics on their website under "Resources."

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll give sfml a try for now.

Comment: Nice, didn't know about this, doesn't look like it works with Qt though.

Answer (score 3):

This is a broad question and likely to get closed but some starting points could be:

- Using [openCL/openGL interoperability](http://sa10.idav.ucdavis.edu/docs/sa10-dg-opencl-gl-interop.pdf) to directly render your data
- If speed is not crucial and you don't mind transferring data back to the host you might use openGL libraries (steep learning curve) or Windows-specific DirectX (hard) or GDI+ (easier and basic graphic capabilities)
- Other simpler alternatives: [sfml](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) or openGL wrappers like [OGLplus](http://oglplus.org/)

**Notice that you didn't describe how you're going to render that data or what are your expectations**. This makes the question impossible to be answered correctly. Just guessing is possible.

Comment: I was thinking about rendering each individual update step as a high res png image and then stitching it together to make a movie.

Comment: You don't need speed then, you might also get away with transferring data on the host and drawing stuff with one of the libraries above

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve your goal. The most common ones would be to use either OpenGL or Direct3D. Both can be hooked with OpenCL. I'm an OpenGL guy, so I'd recommend you OpenGL, but Direct3D is a very nice API if you plan on targeting Windows based systems only.

Take some time and search for the keywords *OpenCL/OpenGL interop* or *OpenCL/Direct3D interop* and you shoul find a lot of stuff.